# Need Help - Count number of times the word "cheese" string appears and print number in java using selenium

Tags: java, string, count, selenium-webdriver

Hi i'm trying to figure out how to count how many times the word "cheese" string appears and print the number using selenium. Here's what I have:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q")); 
    element.sendKeys("cheese"); 
    element.submit(); 


    List <WebElement> links = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));


    for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Link: " + links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
        System.out.println("Title" + links.get(i).getAttribute("title"));
        System.out.println("Description: " + links.get(i).getText()+ "\n");
        //Trying to calculate the total count the word "cheese" from .getText()     
    }
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(links.get(i).getText());
}

String totalResult = stringBuilder.toString();

System.out.println(totalResult.toLowerCase().split("cheese", -1).length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy if you write your selector correctly. Follow this:

```
By byXpath = ".//a/strong[.='cheese' or .='Cheese']" //assuming you want all the cheese ignoring case

//and then find the list and count

IList<IWebElement> list = Driver.FindElements(byXpath);
Console.WriteLine(list.Count.ToString());
```

Using C#